# How to invoke specific method for specific queue, in RabbitMQ with Multiple Queue?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have 2 queues in rabbitMQ, `queueA` and `queueB`

when `queueA` and/or `queueB` is filled with data( via `convertAndSend()` method), it will automatically call `MessageListener.onMessage()` Method (CMIIW).

So, my question is, how can I call `methodA()`, when `queueA` is filled, and call `methodB()` when `queueB` is filled.

Different Method for Different queue

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#async-consumer).

You can use two listener containers (one for each queue) and use a `MessageListenerAdapter` configured to call the appropriate method for each queue (see `setDefaultListenerMethod()`).

You can use a single listener container that listens to both queues, and subclass `MessageListenerAdapter` and implement `getListenerMethodName()` to determine which method to call based on the message. Starting with Spring AMQP version 1.4.2, the queue from which a message was received is available in

```
originalMessage.getMessageProperties().get(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE)
```

Comment: my listener is registered in .xml file

Comment: Wire up the listener container as a `<bean>` or and inject the custom MessageListenerAdapter. I added support for your use case in the upcoming 1.5 release. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/318